# 3 balls are distributed to 3 boxes at random. Number of way in which we set at most 1 box empty is:

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

3 balls are distributed to 3 boxes at random. Number of way in which we set at most 1
box empty is:

**My approach:-**
let no of box = $n$ & no of balls = $k$

and both are distinct.

Now required way ,

zero box empty + 1 box empty

$\implies n_{\mathrm{P }_{k}} + S(k,n) * n!$

$\implies 3_{\mathrm{P }_{3}} + S(3,2)*2$

$\implies 3! + 6 = 12$

where,
$\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{k},
 \mathbf{n}):-$ Stirling number of the second kind can be defined as $\mathrm{S}(\mathrm{k}, \mathrm{n})=\frac{1}{n !} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{i} n_{C_{i}}(n-i)^{k}$

$=\frac{1}{n !}\left[n_{C_{0}}(n-0)^{k}-n_{C_{1}}(n-1)^{k}+n_{C_{2}}(n-2)^{k}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1} n_{C_{n-1}}(1)^{k}\right]$

**Edit $1$**
I think first I have to choose the empty box doing $\binom{3}{1}$,then it becomes 3 balls into 2 boxes. So accordingly I can use the above mentioned process.(i.e $S(2,3)*3*2!$. that will lead me to $24$ .)But here one doubt arises in my mind! I am considering the case one box may contain atleast 1 ball it can go max to 3 balls also.But If I take 3 balls in a box another box will also remain empty ,so it becomes two boxes empty which is invalid.

But answer given is $24$.
**In which step AM I wrong?**

Comment: I think you should use $S(2,3)$ instead of $S(3,3)$ as the number of non empty subsets ie the nonempty boxes in the second case would be $2$.

Comment: I think it may be more usual to write $S(n,k)$ than $S(k,n)$, so the various comments and answers talking about $S(2,3)$ really mean $S(3,2)=3$

Comment: @Henry yeah understood ,still ans is coming 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the balls and boxes are distinguishable, you should have multiplied ${3 \brace 2}$ by $3!$ rather than $2!$ in the case where one box is left empty, where ${n \brace k} = S(n, k)$.

Let's look at the case where exactly one box is left empty.  Two balls must be placed in one box, and the other ball must be placed in another. There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose which two balls are placed together in one box.  If the boxes are indistinguishable, we place these two balls in one box, and place the other ball in another box.  Thus, if the boxes were indistinguishable, the number of ways we can distribute three distinct balls to three indistinguishable boxes so that one box is left empty is
$${3 \brace 2} = \binom{3}{2} = 3$$
If the boxes are actually distinguishable, it matters which box receives two balls, which box receives one ball, and which box receives no balls.  There are $3!$ such assignments.  Thus, the number of ways to distribute three distinct balls to three distinct boxes so that exactly one box is left empty is
$${3 \brace 2}3! = 18$$
Since there are $3!$ ways to distribute three distinct balls to three distinct boxes so that no box is left empty, the number of ways to distribute three distinct balls to three distinct boxes so that at most one box is left empty is
$$3! + {3 \brace 2}3! = 24$$

**An alternate approach**

Assume the boxes are distinguishable from the outset.

*No box is left empty*:  There are $3! = 6$ ways to assign each of the three distinct balls to a different box.

*Exactly one box is left empty*:  If exactly one box is empty, there are three ways to decide which box will receive two balls and two ways to assign a second box to receive the remaining ball.  There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to decide which two balls are placed in the box which will receive two balls and one way to place the remaining ball in the box which will receive one ball.  Hence, there are
$$3 \cdot 2 \cdot \binom{3}{2} = 3!\binom{3}{2} = 18$$
ways to distribute three distinct balls to three distinct boxes so that exactly one box is left empty.

Thus, there are indeed
$$3! + 3!\binom{3}{2} = 6 + 18 = 24$$
ways to distribute three distinct balls to three distinct boxes so that at most one box is left empty.

Comment: please check my edit part

Comment: If you first choose the empty box,  which you can do in three ways, then you must multiply by the $2!$ ways you can assign two balls to one of the other boxes and one way you can assign the remaining ball to the remaining box.  Thus, for the case in which exactly one box is empty, you should have ${3 \brace 2}\binom{3}{1}2! = {3 \brace 2}3!$.

Comment: if i use here S(k,n); will not it be invalid, because the case *3 balls are into 1 box* may arise?

Comment: Remember that ${n \brace k}$ means the number of ways of placing $n$ distinct balls in exactly $k$ indistinguishable boxes.

Comment: okay, that means the case *3 balls are into 1 box* will not at all arise.By default it considers all k boxes atleast contains one ball!

Comment: We are only interested in the cases in which at most one box is left empty.  Thus, the only cases we wish to consider are no box is left empty and exactly one box is left empty.  Notice that there are three ways to place all the balls in one box.  Thus, the total number of possible distributions is $3! + 3!{3 \brace 2} + \binom{3}{1} = 6 + 18 + 3 = 27 = 3^3$, as expected since there are $3^3$ ways to distribute three balls to three distinct boxes without restriction.

Comment: thanks! it is cleared to me now.Big help.+1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110806/discussion-between-amartya-roy-and-n-f-taussig).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you should have $S(2,3)$ not $S(3,3)$ - if one is empty then you are partitioning $n=3$ balls into $k=2$ nonempty (unordered) sets. The factor of $3!$ is correct, because any such partition can be ordered into the three boxes in $3!$ ways.

[edit] The question was changed since this answer was written, and originally had ${}^3P_3+S(3,3)*3!=12$.

Comment: still ans is coming 12. S(3,2)*2! leads to 6. means 6+6 = 12

Comment: @AmartyaRoy It is $S(2,3)\times 3!$, not $S(3,2)\times 2!$.

Comment: Thanks! I have got that from above answer! It is cleared to me now.